# Spring Data JDBC with Azure SQL: After saving the identifier must not be null

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, spring-data-jdbc

Could you help me please with the following error? I am using spring-data-jdbc with Liquibase and Azure SQL Database. I get this when I want to save an object to database with *UserRepository.save*

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: After saving the identifier must not be null!
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:343)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:149)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:55)

Entity:

```
@Table("user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column("email_address")
    String emailAddress;

    @Column("first_name")
    String firstName;

    @Column("last_name")
    String lastName;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDetails, Long> {
}
```

Liquibase:

```
  <changeSet id="0001_user_details">
        <createSequence sequenceName="user_details_seq" startValue="1"/>

        <createTable tableName="user_details">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT" defaultValueSequenceNext="user_details_seq">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="email_address" type="VARCHAR(1024)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>       

            <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>

            <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>  

        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey tableName="user_details" columnNames="id"
                       constraintName="user_details_pk"/>

    </changeSet>
```

Generated Schema:

```
create sequence user_details_seq
go

create table user_details
(
    id               bigint
        constraint DF_user_details_id default NEXT VALUE FOR [user_details_seq] not null
        constraint user_details_pk
            primary key,
    email_address    varchar(1024),
    first_name       varchar(255),
    last_name        varchar(255),
)
go
```

Maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1.jre14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It seems that the issue caused by the **id** column .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your Liquibase configuration correct, it sets up a sequence and sets the default value of the id to the `next` value of that sequence.

This in principle should work, since Spring Data JDBC does not include a `null` id in an insert, assuming it will be generated by the database and returned by the JDBC driver.

That last part is probably where things go wrong.
The exception basically says after inserting the data in the database and using whatever the JDBC driver returned to update the id, the id is still `null` (or `0` if you use a primitive number type).
So probably the driver doesn't return the id generated by the sequence.

In order to solve the problem you have the following options:

1. Don't use a sequence, but create the id on the client side, for example by using a UUID. The benefit of this is that it's easy to implement should scale pretty well. If you create the id upon instantiation of the entity, you may also refer to it before persisting the entity.
2. Use a separate query to select the value from the sequence and use it to set the id. This is probably best done in a `BeforeSaveCallback`, but could also happen in a factory method that creates your entities. This is a little more involved and requires an additional database roundtrip. Which could get mitigated by implementing an algorithm where you select values from a sequence multiply it with say 50 and then generate 50 ids from it locally. Which is basically the HiLo algorithm of Hibernate.
3. Teach Spring Data JDBC how to get the id from the database. This could take many forms and depends on Azure knowledge that I don't have. If Azure has a `SERIAL` or `AUTOINCREMENT` field, that could probably be used instead of the sequence and it should get returned by the JDBC driver.

   Maybe it works when a different `IdGeneration` is used in the `Dialect` you are using. Or maybe a new `IdGeneration` could be implemented. This obviously is rather involved and would take a full new release (or a patched version) of Spring Data JDBC.

Comment: Actually the BeforeConvertCallback did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be wrong annotation used

should be used

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
```

instead of

```
import javax.persistence.Id
```